Working with larger than memory data in numpy
I am working on a project that involves larger than memory numpy 3 dimensional arrays.  The project will be deployed with AWS lambda.  I am faced with two design choices
a) Re-write large parts of the project using numpy memory mapped arrays. This can be easily refactored into the code with decorators writing the array on disk. With lambda, I will be using EFS for disk access
b) Re-write large parts of the project switching numpy array with dask arrays.  I am not familiar with dask arrays, but from what i have read so far it implements familiar interface with numpy.
My questions -
a) Which solution is likely to scale performance wise with more data?
b) Which solution is the easiest to implement in existing codebase?
c) Are there functionalities in dask that allows to easy conversion of existing codebase
I have tried numpy memory mapped arrays and cutting the data into chunks.  Numpy of course still struggles as the data size grows.

you could make your code compatible with the python array api standard using array-api-compat and then you can easily switch between using numpy and dask arrays

a) solution (b) should be more efficient since Dask can perform some optimisation that are hard to do with memory-mapped Numpy array (MMNA). Moreover, MMNA tends to fill memory and cause issues on some platforms not to mention Numpy does not calls unmap yet (so OS resources are not freed which can also be a problem on large scale applications relying on this a lot).

That being said, regarding only scalability, I guess both should be similar. The main parameter for scalability is the hardware itself (see. SLC cache on flash devices) and the memory access pattern (non-contiguous accesses are very slow).
